# Start Cassandra on Mac

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, macos-big-sur, apple-m1

I was working with Apache Cassandra on Windows and for starting it I was using a **cassandra.bat** file.

Now, I have to configure it on a MacBook (M1 chip, Big Sur OS). Is there an equivalent file/command?

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this (which will nicely abstract away your hardware/chipset) would be to use [Docker](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop).  In fact, once you have Docker installed you can get and run the community Docker image in two quick commands:

```
docker pull cassandra:4.0
docker run --name my-cassandra -d -p 9042:9042 cassandra:4.0
```

Note: if you need to run on Cassandra 3, you can simply change the `4.0` tags in the above commands to `3.11`.

Once it's up and running, you can verify it by invoking `nodetool status` inside the container:

```
docker exec -it my-cassandra nodetool status
```

FWIW, the same steps/commands will work on Windows, too.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that you're using the binary tarball for your installation.

Starting Cassandra on a Mac is the same as it is on Linux. Use the following script:

```
$ cd path/to/tarball_installation
$ bin/cassandra
```

The `logs/` and the `data/` directories should all be located in the same location. Cheers!